# How to reset airbag system for Bmw 2006 325i e90?

Tags: bmw, supplemental-restraint-system, 325i

I had an accident and my airbags enabled and i changed airbag unit and now i have some errors for airbag system and seat belts.
How to fix them to disappear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your model comes with seat belt pretensioners? Thiese would also deploy in case you have airbag deployed and must be changed.

Once both fixed you need to reset the error via diagnostic tool.

Comment: Yes it comes and i changed them. Tnx Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily unlike most makes, BMW airbag modules are allowed 3 "hard" resets by OBD2 (codes stored from accident).

You will need a proper scan tool or a j2534 tool to use ISTA from bmw to perform the reset.

If the module has had 3 hard resets already then the only options left are to either manually clear the codes in the eeprom memory or replace the module.